# How do I change the image on a button I created in the Xcode interface builder?

Tags: xcode, button, interface, builder

Using xcode I have created an interface with several buttons, the problem I am having is that I would like to change the image on a button once it has been clicked. I understand how I would do this if I created the button programatically but no idea how to change an image that was created in the interface builder.

I don't really want to start from scratch and build the interface again programmatically so
if anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the button image property:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIImage *currentImage
```

You will need to have established an `IBOutlet` connection to the `UIButton`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your class has a corresponding `UIButton` property for the button:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *m_Button;
```

Then in the User Interface builder you can connect the button and the outlet.
In your code you can then access the button properties like you created it programatically.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Got it working, it  saved me quite a bit of time!