# Styling a button that was created in interface builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, storyboard

If you have a button that was created in Interface Builder and already points to another `viewController` how do you target that button in code to give it a custom background for normal and selected state in code?

```
UIImage *registerButtonNormal = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowRegisterButton"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];

[self.registerButton setBackgroundImage:registerButtonNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];


UIImage *registerButtonSelected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowRegisterButtonSelected"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];

[self.registerButton setBackgroundImage:registerButtonSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the image on a button I created in the Xcode interface builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263418/how-do-i-change-the-image-on-a-button-i-created-in-the-xcode-interface-builder)

Comment: I put this question/answer because I didn't find the other questions/ answers explicit enough. They all left out an important part of the problem that I needed help answering, so when I finally understood it, I decided to share what I had learned in a more explicit way with other beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually really easy.

You just have to create a `@property` and connect the button you want to style by control dragging from the button to the newly created property.

The property should look something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *registerButton;
```

Then in the viewDidLoad, you put the above code that targets your button:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

    // code for styling button goes here. 

    }
```

You can see the code for styling the button in the question.

Comment: You don't need to make the button a property. Simply creating a reference to the button under `@interface` is sufficient. You only need to make the button a property of your class if you plan on accessing the button in other classes. Otherwise, just set the button's scope to the class it's in.

Comment: No, you don't need to make it a property. But that's a better style, and the proper thing for @Arel to have recommended.

Comment: @DaveBatton I hadn't realized. Could you explain why? I thought it was best practice to keep the scope of a variable limited if there is no need to access it from outside the class.

Comment: @JackHumphries I personally feel like Dave Batton, but that is a personal opinion. I like properties that are in fact used from the outside (and I consider a NIB being outside) to be visible outside (within the header).... However, I have seen many (GOOD!) developers doing it differently, just like you. Hence, this is mostly a question of personal style.

Comment: Not all properties make the variable accessible from outside the class.. They can be defined within the implementation inside a second interface clause, effectively making them private.